# How can I filter on showing only gitlab issues that are related to another specific gitlab issue

Tags: gitlab

Is there a way to filter to show only issues that are related to a specific issue? There's ways to filter an assignment and author and such but I can't find how to filter like:

```
linked:[issuenumber]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Gitlab 13.9, no. After searching through all their [issues](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/?scope=all&utf8=%E2%9C%93&state=all), it doesn't seem anyone has even brought it up. That's where I'd start if you're a free tier user, otherwise contact your sales rep or support for paying customers to request it. They tend to implement features faster if it affects paying customers than they do for free users.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, we've got multiple instances of GitLab free and paid so I will feed it up the chain. Thanks again.